# regexReplace in String Manipulation KNIME

Tags: regex, knime

I'm trying to remove the content of all cells that start with a character that is not a number using KNIME (v3.2.1). I have different ideas but nothing works.

1) String Manipulation Node: `regexReplace(§column§,"^[^0-9].*","")`

The cells contain multiple lines, however only the first line is removed by this approach.

2) String Manipulation Node: `regexMatcher($casrn_new$,"^[^0-9].*")` followed by Rule Engine Node to remove all columns that are "TRUE".

The regexMatcher gives me "False" even for columns that should be "True" though.

3) String Replacer Node: I inserted the expression `^[^0-9].*` into the Pattern column and selected "Replace whole String" but the regex is not recognised by that node so nothing gets replaced.

Does anyone have a solution for any of those approaches or knows another Node that might do the job? Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with your first solution, since it has already worked, you just have to expand your regex to include newlines. I would try something like this:

`regexReplace($column$,"^[^0-9].(.|\n)*","")`

This should match any text starting with a character that is not a number, followed by any number of occurrences of any character or a newline. Depending on the line endings, you might need `(.|\n|\r)` instead of `(.|\n)`.

Comment: I actually tried `regexReplace($column$,"^[^0-9](.|\n)*","")` before but it didn't work. `(.|\n|\r)` was the solution to the problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following expression:

```
"(?s)^\D.*$"
```

So the dot will match even new lines. (Based on this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)

In case you need to only change the content of the cells that do not start with a number, I do not think you need to filter any columns or rows. (BTW in case you want to remove rows, there are the Rule-based Row Filter/Splitter nodes which also support regular expressions with the MATCHES predicate.)

Comment: The expression did not work properly in KNIME but it's good to know that `?m` exists. Also thanks for the other information!

Comment: I noticed that you edited the expression and decided to try it with the String Replacer Node. It works totally fine!